# Use Two bpf filter in pyshark

Tags: python, python-3.x, dhcp, pyshark

Can i Use two bpf filter in pyshark.
for e.g,

```
pyshark.LiveCapture(interface = 'wlo2', bpf_filter = 'arp and dhcp')
```

is it possible or is there any way to use 2 filter simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine the BPF filters yourself with `and` or `or`. There can be only one BPF filter active for a capture.

In your example the filter would match packets which are ARP and DHCP but this is not a combination that can exist. ARP is a link-layer protocol in Ethernet while DHCP is built on IPv4/IPv6 and UDP.

To match either ARP or DHCP, just do `arp or dhcp`. To combine more elaborate filters, use parentheses for grouping, such as `(arp and ether host 01:02:03:04:05:06) or (dhcp and host 192.168.0.1)`.

I have found it easier to use BPF filters (fast) for rough pre-selection of packets on the kernel level, then an additional display filter for slower but more flexible final filtering.

Comment: It will clear my query, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333690/how-to-use-two-bpf-filter-simultaneously-in-pyshark @vaizki